# В чём отличия lifetime от storage duration?

Tags: c++, c, объекты, переменные

В чём отличия `lifetime` от `storage duration`? Вроде бы это одно и тоже, но их почему-то разделяют друг от друга. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @eanmos, хорошо, но ваш ответ все равно был полезен:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что lifetime определяется по storage duration.

Lifetime - это то, когда объект будет официально живой и доступен (после вызова delete или по висящей ссылке объект как бы может быть доступен, но вот стоит ли так делать).

storage duration - это как компилятор должен организовать его - сохранить на стеке, в специальном месте для каждого потока, или пользователь сам будет в хипе создавать-удалять.

Если storage duration - стек (раньше это называлось "автоматический"), то время жизни - до парной фигурной скобки. Компилятор сам добавит деструктор в нужное место.

Если storage duration динамический, то время жизни определяется парой new-delete (в новом 20 или 23 стандарте malloc/free тоже может так делать).

Еще есть static, thread и register (который с 17 стандарта официально отдан на откуп компилятору).

Со static внутри функции все очень интересно - объект создается при первом обращении к объекту и будет жить до конца.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Парный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392160/storage-duration-vs-lifetime

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но хотелось бы уточнить: имеет ли `storage duration` какую-либо связь со `scope`?

Comment: "парная фигурная скобка" это и есть пример "scope"

Comment: `register` был спецификатором *класса хранения*, но он не подразумевал отдельную *продолжительность хранения*

Comment: И для `static`-переменных объект **инициализируется** при первом прохождение через его объявление, а не при первом обращении... но память под него выделяется согласно продолжительности хранения...

Comment: я бы уточнил свое выражение так - при первом обращении к статик переменной она будет инициализирована. Если статик переменную определить, но не использовать , то компилятор может выбросить ее. Плюс ко всему, очень сложно объявить статическую переменную внутри функции. (именно объявить, а не определить). Да, я понимаю, это буквоедство, но не я первый это начал

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения языка C, согласно параграфу 1 раздела “6.2.4 Storage durations of objects” стандарта C99:

> Объект имеет продолжительность хранения (англ. storage duration), которая определяет его время жизни (англ. lifetime). Существуют три продолжительности хранения: статическая, автоматическая и динамическая (англ. allocated). <…>

Второй параграф того же раздела гласит

> Время жизни объекта — это часть времени исполнения программы, во время которой гарантируется, что хранилище будет зарезервировано для этого объекта. На протяжении своего времени жизни объект существует, имеет постоянный адрес и хранит последнее сохраненное в него значение. <…>

В целом стандарт определяет зависимость времени жизни объектов от их продолжительности хранения следующим образом:

- Если объект объявлен с классификатором `static` или имеет внешнюю или внутреннюю линковку, то он будет иметь статическую продолжительность хранения, а его время его жизни будет всем временем исполнения программы.
- Если объект не имеет линковки и не объявлен как `static`, то он будет иметь автоматическую продолжительность хранения, а время его жизни начнется с начала соответствующего блока и до его конца.
- Если память для объекта выделена с помощью функций `calloc`, `malloc` или `realloc`, то ему присваивается динамическая продолжительность хранения, и время его жизни длится от момента выделения памяти до момента освобождения.

---

Таким образом, продолжительность хранения — это некоторое свойство объекта, которое определяет то, каким будет время его жизни. То есть на протяжении какого времени, для этого объекта будет зарезервировано место в памяти.

Два разных объекта могут иметь одну и ту же продолжительность хранения, но разное время жизни, например:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
    /* Оба объекта, для которых malloc выделил память имеют
     * динамическую продолжительность хранения.
     *
     * Однако время жизни объекта *a начнется раньше, чем
     * время жизни объекта *b.
     */
    int *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
    int *b = malloc(sizeof *b);

    /* Время жизни объекта *a закончится раньше,
     * чем время жизни объекта *b.
     */
    free(a);
    free(b);
}
```

Продолжительность хранения — это просто некоторая *формальная* информация об объекте, зная которую, мы можем сказать, каким правилам будет подчиняться его продолжительность жизни. В то же время, продолжительность жизни — это уже нечто более «реальное», то что можно наблюдать в реальности.

Comment: Прочел 2 раза, но не уловил, **в чем именно разница** между `lifetime` и `storage duration`

Comment: @avp, немного поменял ответ. Так лучше, как думаете?

Comment: Лучше. Может быть я бы подчеркнул, что storage duration это время, в течении которого есть **доступ к участку памяти**, в котором  размещается объект, а lifetime это время в течении которого можно иметь **доступ к valid объекту**.

Comment: @avp, мне кажется, это не совсем верно. Все-таки, storage duration — это скорее формальный атрибут объектов, просто удобное определение, не несущее никакого «физического» смысла.

Comment: Возможно. Но все зависит от того  что именно мы хотим обсудить. Если "мир языка", которым может упрвлять прикладной программист, то storage duration это невидимая для него вещь. Если говорить о полной реализации, то "физический смысл" очевиден. Storage duration для static это life duration процесса. Storage duration для automatic (stack) и dynamic объектов зависит от реализации управления стеком и виртуальной памятью и того места в программе, где создается объект. В некоторых случаях после окончания lifetime объекта виртуальная память, выделенная ему ранее, тоже может исчезнуть